# how to log in to WP if the "Log in" link under Meta is missing

Tags: metabox

Help Please:  somehow I have stuffed up my WP site, now when I put in my URL and bring up my site there is no  Meta (word) or "log in link" option so I can access my "dashboard", so i cannot get into the back end of my site, can someone please help with directions as to how I can fix this.
Cheers
Cheryl

Comment: http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/ or http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the administration dashboard on your wordpress site, you can use the /wp-admin URL. For example, on http://example.org, one would use http://example.org/wp-admin to access the administration dashboard.